# How do I use clipping in andengine opengl 2.0 ???

Tags: android, andengine

Hi i am new to an andengine and i want to clip some part of screen bt i dont know how to do this. help me..
I am using Andengine EGL 2.0. I found some answers in forum but all are for EGL1.0 but i am using EGL2.0.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. But, you can clip some part of a sprite by changing sprite's region size and position like this: http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/how-to-draw-only-a-part-of-a-sprite-t5605.html#p24903